# Python: using variables declared inside if statement

Tags: python

```
for case in log:
    for event in case:
        if event in process_model:
            index = process_model.index(event)
        else: print(event, index)
```

```
---------- output-----------
NameError: name 'index' is not defined
```

I still need to use index

Comment: I don't understand. What would `index` be in the case that `if event in process_model` is `False`? You can give it a default value before `if event in process_model` but I'm not sure how that fits with "I still need to use index"

Comment: I need to use the value of index when the event not in process_model . The problem is handling if-statement scop. –

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for case in log:
    for event in case:
        if event in process_model:
            index = process_model.index(event)
        else:
            index = None
        print(event, index)
```

Or (if case has a `__repr__` method and you want to be well informed):

```
for case in log:
    for event in case:
        if event in process_model:
            index = process_model.index(event)
        else:
            index = None
        print(case, event, index)
```

Comment: I need the value of index when the event not in process_model . The problem is handling if-statement scop.

Comment: If event isn't in process_model, index won't have a value, since index indicates the location of event in process_model, which it then doesn't have. That's why it's assigned None. It's like asking for the house number of a house that isn't in a street. It simply doesn't have one. Probably you know what you want, but unfortunately I do not understand what exactly it is...